# Leaflet marker cluster clash with geoJSON data filteration

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Following this query:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344396/leaflet-geojson-filteration-clash-with-markercluster-and-map-on-zoomend-function

I am still fighting with matching the leaflet cluster with geojson filteration data.

My full work is based here:

https://mariusz-krukar.mkrgeo.pl/en/workshop/media/MDU_demo.html

but recently I have made a 2nd level filteration based on the following example:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html

Now my situation looks like this:

[image]

I have distinguished another geoJSON properties within the sublayer in the radiO buttons as per in the image above.

The code for one of the layer (mdu) looks like this:

```
         mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {
                            style: style2,
                            pointToLayer: pointVMToLayer,
                            onEachFeature: OnEachVMmduFeature,
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                return (feature.properties.Type == "MDU" );
                            }
                            })//.addTo(map);    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_targets' of null
                                                //MDU data filteration
                                                var mData =  L.layerGroup([]);
                                                mData.addLayer(mdu);
                                                mData.addTo(map); 
                                            
                                        document.getElementById("MDUNew").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                                        theExpression = 'feature.properties.Status == "Issued" ';
                                        console.log(theExpression); 
                                            
                                            mData.clearLayers();
                                            map.removeLayer(mData);
                                            
                                        mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {
                                                style: style2,
                                                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

                                                    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                                                        color:'red',
                                                        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Type),
                                                        fillOpacity: 1,
                                                        radius: 8
                                                    })
                                                },  
                                                onEachFeature: OnEachVMmduFeature,
                                                filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                                     return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU") && (feature.properties.Status == "Issued" );
                                                },

                                            });
                                            
                                            mData.addLayer(mdu);
                                            mData.addTo(map);
                                        }); 

                                        document.getElementById("MDUAll").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    theExpression = 'feature.properties.Type == "MDU" ';
                    console.log(theExpression); 
                        
                        mData.clearLayers();
                        map.removeLayer(mData);
                        
                    mdu = L.geoJson(data2, {
                            style: style2,
                            pointToLayer: pointVMToLayer,
                            onEachFeature: OnEachVMmduFeature,
                            filter: function(feature, layer) {   
                                 return (feature.properties.Type =="MDU");
                            },
                        });
                        
                        mData.addLayer(mdu);
                        mData.addTo(map);
                    });
```

and for the marker clustering:

```
      featuresLayer2a = L.markerClusterGroup({         // layer 2 Virgin Media MDU
                        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
                        showCoverageOnHover: true,
                        zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
                        disableClusteringAtZoom: 17,
                        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
                            var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
                            var c = ' marker-cluster2-';
                            if (childCount < 10) {
                                c += 'small';
                            } else if (childCount < 100) {
                                c += 'medium';
                            } else {
                                c += 'large';
                            }
                            return new L.DivIcon({ 
                            html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker- 
        cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
                            },
                    });
                    featuresLayer2a.addLayers([mdu]);
                        map.addLayer(featuresLayer2a);
                        console.log("Is geojsonLayer in markerClusterGroup? " + 
      featuresLayer2a.hasLayer(geojsonLayer));
```

At the end I would like to add also the map.on('zoomend')function, because I found, that problem is gone when the markercluster layer is not visible anymore...

```
    map.on('zoomend', function() {
      if (map.getZoom() < 9){
      
    if (map.hasLayer(regus)) map.removeLayer(regus);
    if (map.hasLayer(stonewater)) map.removeLayer(stonewater);
    if (map.hasLayer(infill)) map.removeLayer(infill);
    if (map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.removeLayer(mdu);
  //if (map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.removeLayer(featuresLayer2a); - switching off this layer solves the problem, but the clusters are not visible anymore.
     if (map.hasLayer(job3)) map.removeLayer(job3);
    }
     else {
     
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=regus]").checked && !map.hasLayer(regus)) map.addLayer(regus);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=stonewater]").checked && !map.hasLayer(stonewater)) map.addLayer(stonewater);

    if (document.querySelector("input[name=infill]").checked && !map.hasLayer(infill)) map.addLayer(infill);
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=mdu]").checked && !map.hasLayer(mdu)) map.addLayer(mdu); 
    //if (!map.hasLayer(featuresLayer2a)) map.addLayer(featuresLayer2a);
if (document.querySelector("input[name=bt]").checked && !map.hasLayer(job3)) map.addLayer(job3);
```

}
});

One reasonable way to solve it I found here:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/13#issuecomment-37025188

Is anyone able to help?

Thanks & regards